# Iterate through rows and columns, python

Tags: python, pandas

Could you, please, help me to crack the calculation?

I have the following table:

[image]

What I need to do is to calculate the expected frequency as (row total * col total) / grand total

The expected result:
[image]

I assume that I need to iterate through rows and columns. I have tried to do it with:

```
for i, row in df_dropped.iterrows():
for j, column in row.iteritems():
    data[row][column] = df_dropped.iloc[i, 3] * df_dropped.iloc[2, j]
```

The error appears:
Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for outer product of last column and last row and divide by
scalar selected by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to numpy array:

```
t = df.loc['col_sum', 'row_sum']
arr = np.outer(df['row_sum'], df.loc['col_sum']) / t
```

Then create DataFrame by contructor with indexing for remove last column ans row:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr[:-1, :-1], 
                   columns=df.columns[:-1],
                   index=df.index[:-1]).add_prefix('exp_')
print (df1)
   exp_satisfied  exp_neutral  exp_dissatisfied
0      24.605263    20.842105          9.552632
1     145.394737   123.157895         56.447368
```

Get new columns names:

```
cols = [item for x in df.columns[:-1] for item in (x, 'exp_' + x)]
print (cols)
['satisfied', 'exp_satisfied', 'neutral', 'exp_neutral', 'dissatisfied', 'exp_dissatisfied']
```

Join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for expected ordering of columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:-1, :-1], df1], axis=1).reindex(columns=cols)
print (df)
   satisfied  exp_satisfied  neutral  exp_neutral  dissatisfied  \
0         30      24.605263       17    20.842105             8   
1        140     145.394737      127   123.157895            58   

   exp_dissatisfied  
0          9.552632  
1         56.447368
```

Comment: Thank you, jezrael, it is beatifully simple

Comment: Just one more question. Here is the final result: def expected_frequency(data):
    """The function calculates expected frequency"""
    data['row_sum'] = data.sum(axis = 1)
    data.loc['col_sum'] = data.sum()
    t = data.loc['col_sum', 'row_sum']
    arr = np.outer(data['row_sum'], data.loc['col_sum']) / float(t)
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(arr[:-1, :-1], columns = data.columns[:-1]).add_prefix('exp_')
    data = pd.concat([data.iloc[:-1, :-1], data2], axis = 1)
    return data
expected_frequency(df_dropped). My questions, how to store the function table as a permanent table?

Comment: @eponkratova - yes?

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you think assign? `df1 = expected_frequency(df)` - apply function to DataFrame called `df` and assign to `df1`

Comment: Yeah...that was easy. I thought of creating an empty df and then, applying a function to it, if makes sense. It is good to be new, you could come up with completely ridiculous solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Jezrael gave a great answer in which you are calculating the expected frequencies using numpy and pandas. 
You can also use the python statistical libary [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) to calculate these kinds of statistics.

For example to calculate a table of expected frequencies, you could do:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
expected_values = sm.stats.Table(df).fittedvalues
```

More info on: [statsmodels contingency tables](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.Table.html)

Comment: Yeah. I also feel that crosstab could work. Thank you for an one-line solution!